# property about centralizer of maximal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, p-groups, maximal-subgroup

How we can show that for group $G$ (finite non-abelian p-group, I don't know which ones are necessary) and $M$ maximal subgroup of $G$. We can have
$C_G(M)\le C_G(\Phi(G))\le Z(\Phi(G))$
$\Phi(G)$ denote frattini subgroup of G
Left relation kinda simple I don't know if it is true for infinite groups, I'm not sure how right relation is true

Comment: $C_G(M) \le C_G(\Phi(G))$ is true because $\Phi(G) \le M$. It is not true in general that $C_G(\Phi(G)) \le \Phi(G)$, so the second containment is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, $C_G(M) \leq C_G(\Phi(G))$ follows since $\Phi(G) \leq M$.

Also, the second containment is false, for example it is possible that $\Phi(G)$ is central. Consider a nonabelian $p$-group of order $p^3$, or more generally any extraspecial $p$-group.